# Swift: Less code with nested enum cases conforming to equal protocols

Tags: swift, generics, enums

I try to write less code in following scenario:

I have this `Queryable` protocol and a `Parameter` enum:

```swift
protocol Queryable {
    var urlQuery: URLQueryItem { get }
}

enum PaginationParameter: Queryable {
    case page(Int)
    case pageSize(Int)

    var queryItem: URLQueryItem {
        switch self {
        case .page(let page):
            return URLQueryItem(name: "page", value: page.description)
        case .pageSize(let pageSize):
            return URLQueryItem(name: "page_size", value: pageSize.description)
        }
    }
}
```

And an enum that provides some default cases and some specific cases defined by a generic type:

```swift
enum Parameter<P: Queryable> {
    case pagination(PaginationParameter)
    case specific(P)
}
```

#### Example Usage

```swift
enum BookParameters: Queryable {
    case search(String)
    case id(Int)

    var urlQuery: URLQueryItem {
        switch self {
        case .search(let string):
            return URLQueryItem(name: "search", value: string)
        case .id(let id):
            return URLQueryItem(name: "id", value: id.description)
        }
    }
}

let parameters: [Parameter<BookParameters>] = [
    .pagination(.pageSize(10)),
    .specific(.id(123))
]
```

Now I need to get the url query item through both `.pagination` and `.specific` cases.

```swift
let queryItems = parameters.map({
    switch $0 {
    case .pagination(let param):
        return param.queryItem
    case .specific(let param):
        return param.queryItem
    }
})
```

It would be nice to have a way to handle the nested cases combined since they conform to the same protocol. That doesn't work since I have to go to the nested cases through the parent cases:

A small improvement would be to bury the switch statement in an extension for the Parameters enum and let it conform to the `Queryable` protocol as well:

```swift
extension Parameters: Queryable {

    let queryItem: URLQueryItem {
        switch self {
        case .pagination(let param):
            return param.queryItem
        case .specific(let param):
            return param.queryItem
        }
    }
}
```

That results in a one liner but I have only shifted my problem to a different place.

```swift
let queryItems = parameters.map({ $0.queryItem })
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using nested enums with associated values, I don't really see a way to avoid having this extra switch on the top level `Parameter` enum. As far as I am concerned, Swift doesn't provide us with a tool to work with cases in such a way where we could cast all cases with the "same" associated value types to a single case. What you could do is to rethink the existence of `Parameter` type, since it doesn't seem to be really useful due to the fact you still need to refer to it as `Parameter<BookParameters>` or `Parameter<SomeOtherTypeThatConformsToQueryable>`.

Personally I would skip the top level enum, and refer to the `parameters` property type as `[Queryable]` directly.

```swift
var parameters: [Queryable] = [
    PaginationParameter.pageSize(10),
    BookParameters.id(123)
]
```

Makes things much more simpler and easier to reason about. Also there is now a way to add other cases of other types, where it would not be possible with your initial solution.

```swift
enum SomeOtherTypeThatConformsToQueryable: Queryable {
    case aVeryNiceCase(Int)
}

parameters.append(SomeOtherTypeThatConformsToQueryable.aVeryNiceCase(0))
// Appending this to array of type `[Parameter<BookParameters>]`, would not be
// possible without explicitly adding new case to the `Parameter` enumeration
```

Also if you find yourself calling the `map { $0.queryItem }` often, you could provide an extension to the `Array` where `Element` is type of `Queryable`

```swift
extension Array where Element == Queryable {
    var queryItems: [URLQueryItem] { return map { $0.queryItem } }
}

// And now you can simply call
let queryItems = parameters.queryItems
```

Answer (score 1):

Without conforming `Parameters` to `Queryable`, you can just introduce a variable in `Parameters` to get the `queryItem` because both cases accept a type that already conform to `Queryable`,

```
enum Parameter<P: Queryable> {
    case pagination(PaginationParameter)
    case specific(P)

    var urlQuery: URLQueryItem {
        switch self {
        case .pagination(let param):
            return param.urlQuery
        case .specific(let param):
            return param.urlQuery
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: True, however I wonder if there is an easier way since in both cases the return statement is the same.

Comment: Can't think of any.